# How do I do parenthesis in if-statements in Erlang?

Tags: if-statement, erlang

How do I do if-statements like this in Erlang? I have searched but found nothing...

```
if((1 == 1 || 2 == 2 || 3 == 3) && (4 == 4 || 5 == 5 )) {}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the syntax of if statements or boolean expressions? Both are covered in the documentation, and the page is easy to find on your favorite search engine, even when typing the title of your question. The main issue for programmers with a background in imperative language programming is on the actual usage of if statements (and the equivalent of the "else" clause), and this was covered here in more than one question.

Comment: I would like to know the syntax for how to do the multiple parenthesis in Erlang. I can't write like this: if (1 == 1; 2 == 2),(3 == 3; 4 == 4) -> do_something
But I want to write the same logic...

Answer (score 2):

Highly recommended position for Erlang in general (free to read online) and answering your problem here: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#what-the-if

In short, alternative in if (||):

```
if 1 =:= 2; 1 =:= 1 ->
    works
end,
```

Conjunction in if (&&):

```
if 1 =:= 2, 1 =:= 1 ->
    notWorks
end,
```

See also: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions

Comment: I guess you meant that the other way around - `;` corresponds to `||` and `,` corresponds to `&&`.